# iOS - [stringObject class] returns "(null)" from phone contacts? How is this possible?

Tags: ios, string, contacts

So I have let's say:

```
NSString *stringObject = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
NSLog(@"%@", [stringObject class]); - RETURNS "(null)"
```

How is this even possible? And how do you work around something like this?

I am trying to return an empty string in case that string is "(null)".

I've tried:

```
 NSString *lastName = ![stringObject isEqual:@"(null)"] ? stringObject : [NSString string];
```

OR

```
NSString *lastName = ![stringObject isEqualToString:@"(null)"] ? stringObject : [NSString string];
```

OR

```
NSString *lastName = ![stringObject isEqual:[NSNull null]] ? stringObject : [NSString string];
```

OR

```
NSString *lastName = [stringObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] ? [NSString string] : stringObject ;
```

OR

```
NSString *lastName = (stringObject  == nil) ? [NSString string] : stringObject ;
```

Has anyone other suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([stringObject class]));`?

Comment: Still says (null). :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This contact has no last name, and therefore `stringObject` is `nil`.  Verify with some code:

```
NSLog(@"Last name='%@'", stringObject);
```

**EDIT** How to verify:

Simply test if the object is `nil` and better still check if the string has `length > 0`, which you can do as simply as:

```
NSString *stringObject = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
if ([stringObject length]) {
    NSLog(@"Contact last name = '%@'", stringObject);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Contact has no last name; they must play for Brazil");
}
```

Comment: That is true. It has no last name. But I am having issue on how to verify it.

Comment: I can't believe it works with length. This I missed because I saw it returned (null). So I was fixating. Pff.. Oh man.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
NSString *lastName = [stringObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? [NSString string] : stringObject ;
```